# How to use python get distance in depth image using realsense D435?

Tags: python, python-3.x, realsense

Camera: realsense D435

Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04

Language: python

I want to get the distance of a point in image. If I use the aligned image that provided in github, there are many holds and the converted depth pixel to metric value will become 0, 0, 0.

What my idea is:

1. depth image inpainting
2. get depth value from depth image
3. using depth value to calculate distance

Following get distance example in GitHub, the code is:

```
depth = get_depth_at_pixel(depth_frame, pixel_x, pixel_y)
x, y, z = convert_depth_pixel_to_metric_coordinate(depth, pixel_x, pixel_y, camera_intrinsics)
```

I found that the output `depth` is float.

Now, I can get value from depth image, which is in numpy.uint16.(e.g. `depth_image[200][100]` is 300)

1. Can I convert depth image to double/float, so that I can get the distance?
2. If `yes`, How can I convert depth image to double/float value?

Answer (score 2):

```
depth_float32 = depth.astype(np.float32)
```